# CSS hover does not react

Tags: css, hover

Why `li::hover` does not react when hover the cursor on `<li>`?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;    
    font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", sans-serif;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li::hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="listbar.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Python</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>Ruby</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>Lisp</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one colon in li:hover will do.
One colon is used to indicate a pseudo-class (a small set of possible states such as link, visited, hover, first-child) or certain legacy pseudo-element (before and after); two colons indicate a CSS3 pseudo-element (see [reference](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors)). A pseudo-element is an element on the page that's implied by its location or context; a pseudo-class is a variation on an existing element.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;    
    font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", sans-serif;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="listbar.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Python</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>Ruby</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
            <li>Lisp</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some css selector use two colon.
What's the difference of two and one?

Comment: Added a bit more explanation in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works great except that

```
li::hover {
```

needs to be

```
li:hover {
```

You had an extra colon in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need write like that:

```
  li:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
```